# HTML how can I preprocess text when clicking submit

Tags: php, html

I have a form that is using get as its method. The structure looks something like this:

```
<form class="form-download" method="get" id="download" action="dest.php">
<h1 class="form-download-heading">Process</h1>
<input type="text" name="destid" id="destid" size="40" placeholder="Input" />
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="type" id="type" value="Download" />
</form>
```

The problem is that I want the contents of the field `destid` to be processed when I click the submit button but BEFORE anything else, i.e. before it gets into the URL bar.

I have seen many examples that simply do not do that while using the GET method, so I would like to know how can I fix this problem.

Comment: use POST method for safe processing..

Comment: what do you mean by processed? The only way to manipulate data without posting it to the server is with javascript (or VBScript if you are a time traveler)

Comment: use javascript to prevent the form submitting and then process the input and then use `this.form.submit()` to submit the form using javascript.

Comment: `$("#destid").blur(function() { //do stuff });` , but since you didn't tag javascript, you'll have to submit the form and check server side meaning using PHP.

Comment: Sorry, I have no problem using javascript. I just didn't tag it because I thought the question was more pertinent to html. I'll try your method.

Comment: @Naruto Your solution worked fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can include an `onsubmit` event in the form, like this:

```
<form class="form-download" method="get" id="download" onsubmit="myFunction()" action="dest.php">
```

The `onsubmit` event will fire before the `action`.

That way, when you click the submit button, you can process the contents of the field `destid` before anything else.